# Spring Boot 1.5 @JdbcTest failing when using Eureka Discovery

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to use the new @JdbcTest annotation in Spring boot 1.5.0.RC1.

My app uses Eureka discovery ie I have

`compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')`

in my build.gradle and

`@EnableDiscoveryClient`

on my main Spring Boot class

When I try to use @JdbcTest to test a JdbcTemplate based DAO I get this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method eurekaHealthIndicator in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration$EurekaHealthIndicatorConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient' in your configuration.
```

It looks like the auto configuration is loading part of the Eureka configuration when it should only load JDBC related beans.

If I add

`@TestPropertySource(properties={"eureka.client.enabled=false"})`

to the test the problem goes away, but I think @JdbcTest should be making sure already that only relevant beans are loaded.

Am I missing something or is this a problem with the new @JdbcTest, or maybe Spring Cloud Eureka?

Comment: Try to add these options to your test props: `eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false` and `eureka.client.fetch-registry=false` and `endpoints.health.enabled=false`

Comment: As I said it works when I add eureka.client.enabled=false. But the idea of @JdbcTest is that it is only concerned with the JDBC layer of the application. I shouldn't have to start working out which extra dependencies I have in my overall application are causing problems and how to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@SpringBootApplication` has `@ EnableDiscoveryClient` on it. When you use a slice annotation (such as `@JdbcTest`), Spring Boot finds the context to use by looking at the package of your test for a `@SpringBootConfiguration`. If it does not find one, it looks in the parent package, etc. With a sensible package structure and no further customization, your tests use your `@SpringBootApplication` as the root context.

So, that configuration class (and only that one) is processed an `@EnableDiscoveryClient` is also obviously processed. In your case, this has an additional side effect: every single test now requires the Eureka Client.

`TL;DR` never put such annotation on your application. And only put it if you actually need it. You could define a `@Configuration` class next to your Spring Boot app for those.

Comment: "never put such annotation on your application" - This is new to me, most examples seem to do this including https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery and the 'Quick Start' at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/, so I'm not sure why you should not do this (and I would not have the annotation unless I needed it!). 
I suppose I could move the annotation, but really seems to be moving your core config around in order to suit the implementation of the test slice functionality?

Comment: I told you that in the context of slicing. If you don't want your tests to use your app as the source then create a dedicated `@SpringBootConfiguration`. Try to take a step back, you can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

@David
I had similar issue and fixed by adding the following to my application.yml file

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```